# Getting rid of FeatureEnvy when dealing with data in a method

Tags: ruby, reek, feature-envy

I'm often encountering methods where the handling of data is necessary in order to achieve certain process, in general something like:

```
def process_something(data_from_external_service)
  request_params = {
    param1: data_from_external_service['param1'],
    param2: data_from_external_service['param2'],
    param3: data_from_external_service['param3']
  }
  post_action('some other service param', request_params)
end
```

Considering that:

1. The post action is logically expected to be inside that method (also handling that data), and doing the params preparation somewhere else would probably raise the same reek in the other method that calls `process_something`.
2. `data_from_external_service` is precisely that, those are values coming from outside the app, and creating a new class just to handle that set of data seems to me an excessive measure.

Is there a "legal" way of getting rid of the FeatureEnvy reek?. The only thing I'm doing now is adding `# :reek:FeatureEnvy` on top of the method.